# excel/powershell - find multiple cells that match a string not just the last one

Tags: excel, powershell

Is it possible to find all cell references that contain a specific string in powershell? $Range.Find always just returns the last cell in the sheet, I want all the cells (or do I have to loop through each row? *groan*).

```
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.Visible = $true
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\some.xlsx")
$MySheet = $Excel.Worksheets.Item("somesheet")
$Range = $MySheet.UsedRange
$Targets = $Range.Find("Cheese")

Foreach ($Target in $Targets)
{
Write-Host $Target.AddressLocal()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use:

```
$Target = $Range.Find("Cheese")
$First = $Target
Do
{
    Write-Host $Target.AddressLocal()
    $Target = $Range.FindNext($Target)
}
While ($Target -ne $NULL -and $Target.AddressLocal() -ne $First.AddressLocal())
```